# ExtJs 4 Store's AJAX proxy is not called on Store add — what is missing?

Tags: extjs4, store

I have a Grid, a Store and Model for its data and AJAX proxy for the Store that is pointing to my self-written PHP back-end. The PHP backend writes to log each time it is called.

The system works OK for Read, Update and Delete calls. However now I need to add new  field to Store, which I do in such a way:

(here, some new data were generated...)

```
var newEntry=Ext.ModelManager.create({   
     id:id,
     title: title,
     url: '/php/'+fname,
     minithumb: '/php/'+small,
     thumb:'/php/'+thumb
                }, 'MyApp.model.fileListModel');
 var store=Ext.getCmp('currGallery').getStore();
 store.add(newEntry);
    store.sync();
```

I have the new line appearing in the Grid.
 But with or withour sync() call, I have no calls going to my PHP back end. It however reads one more time. Store has parameter autoSync :true and does great updating data automatically when I edit existing line in the Grid.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I was missing a

```
 newEntry.phantom = true;
```

flag. After I set it before adding to store, Store and its Proxy started to send data to server.

Maybe ID solution also works, dunno.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to set `id` when creating new record.